# Laravel Eloquent Polymorphic Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I had a situation come up where I needed an Eloquent model to hydrate dynamically into a specific class that extends my "normal" eloquent model. Here's a generic layout loosely based on typical electronics:

Data Object:

```
['id', 'model_type', 'name', 'serial',...]
```

- Model

  - Model Type A
  - Model Type B

If the data is all in a single table (MySQL), Laravel doesn't really have a way to pull that data directly as a polymorph. You can polymorph a relationship, but not a model directly.

Essentially the reasoning for this is to separate logic that may be concerned with one type, but not another. For example, `Model Type A` and `Model Type B` can both implement an interface which describes their capabilities, but the specific logic for A doesn't need to pollute B.

Answer (score 6):

My solution for this is to override the `newFromBuilder` method on the model (Laravel 5.6). Like so:

App\Schemes\BaseScheme

```
abstract class BaseScheme extends Electronic
{
    // abstract methods to implement
    // ...
}
```

App\Schemes\ElectronicTypeA

```
class ElectronicTypeA extends BaseScheme
{
    // Electronic Type A logic
}
```

App\Schemes\ElectronicTypeB

```
class ElectronicTypeB extends BaseScheme
{
    // Electronic Type B logic
}
```

App\Models\Electronic

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Electornic extends Model
{
    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
    {
        if (!class_exists($attributes->model_type)) {
            throw new \Exception("Invalid Scheme ({$attributes->model_type})"); 
        }

        $class = $attributes->model_type;
        $model = new $class;

        if (!$model instanceof \App\Schemes\BaseScheme) {
            throw new \Exception("Scheme class is invalid ({$attributes->model_type})");
        }

        $model->exists = true;

        $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

        $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

        $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);

        return $model;
    }
```

Where `\App\Schemes\BaseScheme` is the abstract all the logic models extend. `\App\Schemes\BaseScheme` also extends the original Eloquent model.

The *really* nice thing about this is that it works on the returned collection too. So you can interact with the model just as if it were a normal model--but you're really interacting with the specific classes (typeA, typeB).

Answer (score 2):

There is a Solution.

You can Use This Library :
[Parental](https://github.com/calebporzio/parental)

```
composer require "calebporzio/parental=0.9"
```

and extend child model using The Trait.
Then you can make a Laravel Scope to query child Model.
This is an Example:

```
//parent model
class RoleUser extends Model{
}
```

and for child model:

```
class Expert extends RoleUser
 {
 use \Parental\HasParent;
 public static function boot()
 {
     parent::boot();
     static::addGlobalScope("role", function ($query) {
         $query->where("role_type", "App\Expert");
     });
 }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Yeah, looks like a built-out package following a similar approach noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50107149/1155425

Comment: Yeah. This package handles the table name resolving, and relations in The Child Model and make the code tidy just with using a Trait.